# sharepoint designer workflow: is it possible to trigger actions when a file is minor and when a file becomes major?

Tags: designer-workflow, flow, classic-experience, power-automate

I know I can achieve this with approval by putting the approval status as a condition, I was wondering if there is a way to say than when the file is 1.2, 3.5 or 6.99 to do an action and when it is 3.0, 5.0, 345.0 to do another.

Interested in knowing if this is possible with Flow instead of SPD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to both questions.

In Microsoft Designer, you can use the `Set Variable` action (or similar actions) to retrieve the "UI Version" Property of the List Item.  Then use the `If any value equals ...` action to validate if the version ends with ".0", see the following screenshot: 
 [image: Check Major Version SPD Workflow Actions]

In a Power Automate built Flow, you can do something similar by using a `Condition` action to check if the the "Version Number" value of a List Item ends with ".0", see the following screenshot:
[image]

Comment: in the SPD example, is there any problem if instead of the variable I use If current item: version ends with .0?

Comment: That should work just as well.  Keep mind that if you need to use that version value multiple times (either for multiple comparisons, or to put in an email notification, etc.). It is more efficient to get it from the item once and store in a variable that use multiple times than it is to lookup the same value from the item multiple times.